# Icon resource path

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there any API function to parse links like these: `C:\Path\To\Exe.exe,1`?

Where it will parse the path and icon index so I can use `ExtractIcon` to load it?

Since `Exe.exe,1` is a valid file name, i'm having trouble distinguishing it from a regular path.

Comment: No function can distinguish `Exe.exe,1` from a regular file name. You have to know whether or not the string contains an icon index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`PathParseIconLocation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773737.aspx).

Comment: It's amazing that the API has a function for such a trivial operation.